# Run Bash script before every print job

Tags: bash, printing

I'm using refilled printer cartridges that don't show ink levels, so I made a bash script that keeps count of printed pages (from CUPS log) and shows a warning when it reaches about 200 pages (known limit for the cartridge). Is there a way to run this script every time CUPS does a print job?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using incron to trigger the script whenever the cups log changes.